# What Does the 'Shrine of Skill Mastery' do?

Tags: torchlight-2

I just came across something called *Shrine of Skill Mastery*.  I activated it, and there was a glowy effect around my character, and a noise, but I didn't receive anything as far as I can work out.

What did this do?

[image: Shrine of Skill Mastery]

*This is what it looks like, but I've already activated it*

Comment: I suspect that it adds +X to all your skills.  Double-check your skill levels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Shrine of Skill Mastery provides a bonus of +2 to all skills in which you've already spent at least 1 point. It also reduces the mana cost of all skills by 25% for the duration that the buff is active.

For future reference, you can find out what any buff does by mousing over the icon it leaves near your health orb -  the tooltips are usually pretty clear.